# How to fix Android game that got rejected by ad content?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, publish

My game rejected with this messsage;

Ad Content
We found an issue with the ad content in your app:
Your app contains ad content that is not appropriate for children. Specifically, your app contains ad content that displays:
Inappropriate Media Content: Ads for TV shows, movies, music albums, or any other media outlet that are not appropriate for children.

Inappropriate Video Games & Downloadable Software: Ads for downloadable software and electronic video games that are not appropriate for children.

Controlled or Harmful Substances: Ads for alcohol, tobacco, controlled substances, or any other harmful substances.

Gambling: Ads for simulated gambling, contests or sweepstakes promotions, even if free to enter.

Adult and Sexually Suggestive Content: Ads with sexual, sexually suggestive and mature content.

Dating or Relationships: Ads for dating or adult relationship sites.

Violent Content: Ads with violent and graphic content that is not appropriate for children.

But I blocked all sensetive categories on admob, this categories should'nt be displayed. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you enabled the family program? To also include children under 12-13 years old?

Comment: no I didn't enabled the family program and yes children under 12-13 included. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If in "Play Console target audience and content" you add children under the age of 12, you automatically enter the "Program for children and families" (which has restrictions on the use of ads) (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9893335)

If you want to continue to remain in the "Program for children and families" you will have to go to AdMob and define a category of content suitable for children (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7562142)

Otherwise, if you do not want to change the category and enable all ads you will have to "exit" from the "Program for children and families", by going to "Target audience and contents of Play Console" and disable the boxes under 12 (So you must have enabled only 13-15, 16-17, 18 or more)

---

Edit:

Apparently another step is required that I was not aware of.

> you’ll need to include code that calls the
> tagForChildDirectedTreatment () method for ad requests served to
> children and also specify the maximum ad content rating

The documentation and the code can be found here: (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccode-sample-for-implementation-in-apps-for-everyone-including-children-and-families)

Comment: My content rating on admob was on mature level, now I changed it to G-rated for the family program. Probably the problem was that. I thought blocking categories was enough but apparently it doesn't work like that. Now I am waiting for review, I will update here according to answer from google play. Thank you for the taking time to answer my question!

Comment: it rejected again so I set target audience to 13+ and sent to the review and it published. I didn't wanna deal with family program anymore :/

Comment: Did they reject it for the same reasons? Consider that if you have a mediation network you have to set the ad content there as well. Also I don't know if the setting of the ad content is automatic,, maybe it could take at least a few days, if as soon as you set it you sent it too that could be the problem. I also recommend you to read all the policy regarding the family program, there may be other things to consider besides the content of the ads.

Comment: Yes it was the same mail. I probably missing out something about family policy, I am going to keep searching.

Comment: I added a part to the answer, maybe that's what you were looking for.